# Trying to execute self extracting zip file silently in command line

Tags: zip, executable, exe, self-extracting, winzip

I have these self extracting zip files that I'm trying to extract on 2008/7 machines remotely. But they are coming in a way of .exe and it require user to double click and choose the extractions location.

On WinZip support site they saying to use the /auto flag so the command will look like that:

C:\deploy\.exe /auto C:\path\\

It starts the process in the task manager but it stuck there foever.

[image: Self extracting exe file]

When I'm opening the file in text editor it says: !This program cannot be run in DOS mode.

So maybe anyone of you know how I can automate the extraction of the self extraction file silently. Or maybe there is a way to run them with answer file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this is older, but I  just found this page trying to do the same thing (for a silent driver install)

What the OP put up above works fine.

For example, my line was:

```
UPS_319_117.exe /auto .\upstemp\
```

(This was after having the batch file create the upstemp folder). My guess is either the path was wrong so the self-extracting hit an error in the OP's case, or something along those lines and it just hung up waiting for input that wouldn't happen since it was in auto mode...

Answer (score 1):

You can usually unzip these using a third-party ZIP extraction utility.

Comment: I need a way to do it without maybe with response files or something like that. It's secured environment and I'm not allowed to install there any third party solution.

Comment: @DmitryR Are you perhaps allowed to use a different ZIP compression utility to create these files?

Comment: Nope unfortunately, I'm getting them like this from the application vendor

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I eventually resolved it with PowerShell. Rename your .exe file to a .zip file.  Then run a command like this:

powershell -Command "MD C:\PathWhereFileShouldExtractTo; $shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application; $zip = $shell.NameSpace('C:\PathToZipFile\YourFile.zip'); foreach ($item in $zip.items()) {; $shell.Namespace('C:\PathWhereFileShouldExtractTo').CopyHere($item); }"

I stole the basic PowerShell commands from this article about how to unzip a file with Powershell: [How to unzip a file in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768303/how-to-unzip-a-file-in-powershell)