# How to unzip a file in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a `.zip` file and need to unpack its entire content using Powershell. I'm doing this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace("C:\a.zip")
MkDir("C:\a")
foreach ($item in $zip.items()) {
  $shell.Namespace("C:\a").CopyHere($item)
}
```

What's wrong? The directory `C:\a` is still empty.

Comment: If you're in Powershell 2.0, or without .NET 4.5 installed, then the method you mentioned is the only path (without going with a 3rd-party exe (i.e. 7zip). I would say that the question isn't fully answered until someone provides why this method doesn't work. It does for me some of the time, but others it doesn't.

Comment: Since `Expand-Archive` now exists in powershell, the accepted answer is a bit out of date.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Here is a simple way using [ExtractToDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=netframework-4.5) from [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netframework-4.5):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function Unzip
{
    param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)

    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}

Unzip "C:\a.zip" "C:\a"
```

Note that if the target folder doesn't exist, ExtractToDirectory will create it. Other caveats:

- Existing files will not be overwritten and instead trigger an IOException.
- This method requires at least .NET Framework 4.5, available for Windows Vista and newer.
- Relative paths are not resolved based on the current working directory, see [Why don't .NET objects in PowerShell use the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246068/why-dont-net-objects-in-powershell-use-the-current-directory)

See also:

- [How to Compress and Extract files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files) (Microsoft Docs)

Comment: There is no need to quote the parameters C:\a.zip or C:\a unless there is a space in the path.  PowerShell considers parameters to be of type string or numeric unless the argument starts with a special character like $, @, ( or {.  This is one of benefits of PowerShell being a `shell` scripting language. :-)

Comment: Why do you create a function to replace a single function call?

Comment: In theory you don't. I try to hide complex/unconventional calls in functions so later I can replace the method without worrying about where it's used. As Keith mentioned, in V5 there will be a new way to do it.

Comment: You need at least .NET Framework 4.5 for this. See the bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried this but getting below error,

`Exception calling "ExtractToDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "End of Central Directory record could not be found."
At line:5 char:5
+     [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $ou ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidDataException`

Comment: This gives me the following error: `Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem' could not be found.`. I have .NET 4.6.2 installed, and I've verified that the assembly is in the GAC, but I didn't figure out why I'm getting this error.

Comment: I misclicked a downvote instead of an upvote, sorry about that.

Comment: One serious limitation of this approach (when it works) is that destination directory cannot already exist. If it does, you will get an exception and there is no way to force it overwrite existing files either.

Comment: @MickyBalladelli why does this not run in the current location? I tried modifying your code to accept a location and it calls Set-Location before trying to extract but its just looking for the zip on my local computer

Answer (score 692):

In PowerShell v5+, there is an [Expand-Archive command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/Expand-Archive?view=powershell-6) (as well as Compress-Archive) built in:

```
Expand-Archive C:\a.zip -DestinationPath C:\a
```

Comment: Use `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` to determine what version of PowerShell you are running.

Comment: @LoneCoder I don't think you can blame Ballmer. Windows has *never* had a built in command line tool for handling compressed files before, even though gzip came out in 1992 and tar is even older.

Comment: @Ghashange PowerShell 5 wasn't even available for anything below Windows 10 and Server 2012 when this answer was posted, even as a pre-release.

Comment: Looks like the parameter `OutputPath` has been changed to `DestinationPath` (reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.archive/Expand-Archive)

Comment: You can also use relative paths like
`Expand-Archive -Path .\a.zip -DestinationPath .`

Comment: Warning: Expand-Archive is much slower than 7zip. See https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/32

Comment: Note the `Expand-Archive` and `Compress-Archive` require that archive file extension is `.zip`, while `[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]`-based solutions don't.

Comment: At least in 5.1 simply **Expand-Archive .\my.zip newOutputFolder** to unzip to new subfolder of current directory

Comment: FYI for future readers. Expand-Archive will create the complete DestinationPath if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jonathan in newer versions of PowerShell `Expand-Archive` [with its `-PassThru` option] outputs the files it's expanding and is useful for further processing down the pipeline, which .NET's `ZipFile` can't automatically do :(

Answer (score 36):

In PowerShell v5.1 this is slightly different compared to v5. According to MS documentation, it has to have a `-Path` parameter to specify the archive file path.

```
Expand-Archive -Path Draft.Zip -DestinationPath C:\Reference
```

Or else, this can be an actual path:

```
Expand-Archive -Path c:\Download\Draft.Zip -DestinationPath C:\Reference
```

[Expand-Archive Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: There is no difference between v5 and v5.1 in this Cmdlet. You do not need to name the first parameter; it will automatically become the path. For example, `Expand-Archive Draft.Zip -DestinationPath C:\Reference` works without issue. In addition, it's not *actual* path, but *absolute* path.

Answer (score 28):

Use `Expand-Archive` cmdlet with one of parameter set:

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath C:\source\file.Zip -DestinationPath C:\destination
```

```
Expand-Archive -Path file.Zip -DestinationPath C:\destination
```

Answer (score 14):

Hey Its working for me..

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace("put ur zip file path here")
foreach ($item in $zip.items()) {
  $shell.Namespace("destination where files need to unzip").CopyHere($item)
}
```

Comment: If one of the files or directories already exists at the destination location, it pops up a dialogue asking what to do (ignore, overwrite) which defeats the purpose. Does anyone know how to force it to silently overwrite?

Comment: Answering to the comment by @OlegKazakov: there is set of option controlling the `CopyHere` method. I guess @OlegKazakov already solved his issue. Nevertheless I put this link here for other surfers who can find this topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/sidebar/system-shell-folder-copyhere

Answer (score 13):

Use the built in powershell method `Expand-Archive`

Example

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath C:\archive.zip -DestinationPath C:\
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `expand-archive` but auto-creating directories named after the archive:

```
function unzip ($file) {
    $dirname = (Get-Item $file).Basename
    New-Item -Force -ItemType directory -Path $dirname
    expand-archive $file -OutputPath $dirname -ShowProgress
}
```

Comment: This necessarily expands in the current directory, doesn't it?

Comment: Don't really see the added value of auto creating. It's more flexible to add a second parameter `outputPath` like in the accepted answer. In this solution (as jpmc26 said), you will always create a new directory in the current directory so it's possible you need to set the current directory before you call `unzip`

Comment: Most archivers extract into a dir named after the archive, in the same place as the archive. Nothing to stop you adding parameters if you want something different, but it's a sensible default.

Answer (score 5):

For those, who want to use **Shell.Application.Namespace.Folder.CopyHere()** and want to hide progress bars while copying, or use more options, the documentation is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/folder-copyhere

To use powershell and hide progress bars and disable confirmations you can use code like this:

```
# We should create folder before using it for shell operations as it is required
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "C:\destinationDir" -Force

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$zip = $shell.Namespace("C:\archive.zip")
$items = $zip.items()
$shell.Namespace("C:\destinationDir").CopyHere($items, 1556)
```

Limitations of use of Shell.Application on windows core versions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/what-is-server-core

On windows **core** versions, by default the **Microsoft-Windows-Server-Shell-Package** is not installed, so shell.applicaton will not work.

***note***: Extracting archives this way will take a long time and can slow down windows gui

Answer (score 2):

```
function unzip {
    param (
        [string]$archiveFilePath,
        [string]$destinationPath
    )

    if ($archiveFilePath -notlike '?:\*') {
        $archiveFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($PWD, $archiveFilePath)
    }

    if ($destinationPath -notlike '?:\*') {
        $destinationPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($PWD, $destinationPath)
    }

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

    $archiveFile = [System.IO.File]::Open($archiveFilePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
    $archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]::new($archiveFile)

    if (Test-Path $destinationPath) {
        foreach ($item in $archive.Entries) {
            $destinationItemPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($destinationPath, $item.FullName)

            if ($destinationItemPath -like '*/') {
                New-Item $destinationItemPath -Force -ItemType Directory > $null
            } else {
                New-Item $destinationItemPath -Force -ItemType File > $null

                [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($item, $destinationItemPath, $true)
            }
        }
    } else {
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToDirectory($archive, $destinationPath)
    }
}
```

Using:

```
unzip 'Applications\Site.zip' 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Site'
```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose `$archive` and `$archiveFile` at the end

Answer (score 0):

`ForEach` Loop processes each ZIP file located within the `$filepath` variable

```
    foreach($file in $filepath)
    {
        $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file.FullName)
        foreach($item in $zip.items())
        {
            $shell.Namespace($file.DirectoryName).copyhere($item)
        }
        Remove-Item $file.FullName
    }
```

Comment: "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."