# PowerShell script to download a zip file and unzip it

Tags: powershell, zip, powershell-2.0

I need some help in putting my thoughts together in a working code.

This is what I have:

1st Step: I am getting the FTP user name and password as params.

```
param(#define parameters
[Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$FTPUser
[Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$FTPPassword    
[Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Version    
)
```

I then set these variables:

```
$FTPServer = "ftp.servername.com"
$SetType = "bin"
```

Now, I want to establish a connection. I Google'd for Syntax and found this. Not sure if this will establish a FTP connection. I am yet to test,

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
    $webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($FTPUser,$FTPPassword)
```

This is the part I do not know how to code:

`$Version` is one of my input parameter. I have a zip file in FTP as:

```
ftp.servername.com\builds\my builds\$Version\Client\Client.zip
```

I want to download that Client.zip into my local machine's (where the script is run from) `"C:\myApp\$Version"` folder. 
So, the FTP download will create a new sub-folder with the `$version` name with in `C:\myApp` for every run.

Once this is done, I also need to know how to unzip this client.zip file under `C:\myApp\$Version\Client\<content of the zip file will be here>`

Comment: Unzip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768303/how-to-unzip-a-file-in-powershell or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive     . I would also consider looking into the WinSCP Assembly for Powershell https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell

Answer (score 15):

You may use the `Expand-Archive` cmdlet. They are available in Powershell version 5. Not sure with previous versions. See syntax below:

`Expand-Archive $zipFile -DestinationPath $targetDir -Force`

The `-Force` parameter will force to overwrite the files in target directory if it exists.

With your parameters, it will look like this:

`Expand-Archive "C:\myApp\$Version\Client.zip" -DestinationPath "C:\myApp\$Version" -Force`

Comment: Thanks @alltej, Can it open https uri?

Answer (score 2):

```
Add-Type -assembly "System.IO.Compression.Filesystem";
[String]$Source = #pathA ;
[String]$Destination = #pathB ;
[IO.Compression.Zipfile]::ExtractToDirectory($Source, $Destination);
```

or

```
[IO.Compression.Zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source,$Destination);
```

Depending on if you are trying to zip OR unzip.