# How to download an entire dropbox directory in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, dropbox, powershell-5.0

I've tried a simple:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dropboxStuff/dropboxStuff?dl=1 -O DirectoryName
```

But it's downloading a zip file.

- What is the best way to download and unzip with only powershell
  commands?
- Could this be done in one line?

Comment: What version of PowerShell? Newer releases have a cmdlet that unpacks zipfiles, older versions require a bit of work with COM objects.

Comment: Added tag for power shell and windows version. Thank you @alroc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in one line with PowerShell 5's `Expand-Archive` cmdlet:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dropboxStuff/dropboxStuff?dl=1 -O temp.zip; Get-Item temp.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath "FolderName"; Remove-Item temp.zip
```

You *may* be able to do it by piping `Invoke-WebRequest` to `Expand-Archive` with `-PassThru` but I haven't been able to make it work yet.

Answer (score 3):

In Powershell v5

```
Expand-Archive c:\a.zip -DestinationPath c:\a
```

To know your PS vesion

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

If you don't have PS v5

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function Unzip
{
    param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)

    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}

Unzip "C:\a.zip" "C:\a"
```

Source: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768303/how-to-unzip-a-file-in-powershell)

Comment: Is wget the best way to do the download in powershell? how can I pipe the result of the download to this command?

Comment: @GiulioCaccin Expand-Archive accepts pipeline input.  So you can do `Get-Item [zipfile] | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath C:\etc`

Comment: @GiulioCaccin I'd suggest using `Invoke-WebRequest` over `wget`. By default, `wget` is aliased to that cmdlet but one shouldn't use aliases in scripts, and if you don't have that alias and you're really using `wget`, it will be an external dependency which makes your script less portable.

Comment: Thank you @alroc! If you edit the response with the oneline command i can mark this as the answer.