# Expand-Archive odd errors

Tags: powershell, unzip

I am trying to get at some data in an Autodesk Revit file, which is just a ZIP under the skin. I can use 7zip to extract but I am hoping to automate things with all native PS or Windows. I tried Expand-Archive after I renamed the RVT file to ZIP, but Expand-Archive has an odd error. The code is

```
Expand-Archive -path:'C:\RevitVersionTest\22-PLUMB-CLR-RECTANGULAR.zip' -destinationPath:'C:\Revit Fam'
```

And the error is

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "3" argument(s): "End of Central Directory record could not be found."

Comment: It thinks the zip file is malformed. Can you open it with other zip utilities? Can WIndows Explorer open it?

Comment: @zdan, I can use 7zip, either manually or using it's command line option from within PS. But Explorer claims the file is invalid even after a rename.

Comment: Maybe the input file format isn't quite zip compliant enough. Try getting 7-zip to rezip it to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 5):

#### The file is corrupt. Re-download (or obtain) the ZIP file.

Background: I landed here having experienced the same error downloading a ZIP from Google Drive through a private link:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $zipFile -OutFile "$destPath\myZip.zip"
```

...then using the [command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27771099/3063884):

```
Expand-Archive c:\a.zip -DestinationPath c:\a`
```

The file downloaded but it wouldn't extract. I downloaded through the browser using the UI, and then compared the download file sizes. Sure enough, the downloaded ZIP was corrupted. When I updated the URL to a [Google Docs link directly to the file](https://lifehacker.com/share-direct-links-to-files-in-google-drive-and-skip-th-1493813665) (that's public with permission), the ZIP then downloaded and extracted correctly.

Hence, comments under the question alluding to the file being corrupt are correct.