# Unzip and access folder with powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a powershell script the downloads a zip file with a folder with files within it to the %TEMP% folder and I'm trying to understand how it can be unziped and acessed an exe file within it?

I have made searches both here and on google but I didn't found anything and have no clue how can that be done or evn where to start.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+uncompress+a+zip+in+powershell&oq=how+to+uncompress+a+zip+in+powershell&aqs=chrome..69i57.9647j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 Google search works for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unzip a file in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768303/how-to-unzip-a-file-in-powershell)

Comment: Thank you both of your where useful to understand and find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try `Extract-ZipFile` cmdlet. Then access the exe where you have extracted the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Try expand-archive to unzip files. Power shell v5 has it